# Rails pessimistic locking strategy not working in a Rails 7 / Postgresql app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, locking

In a Rails 7 app, with Postgresql database, I have a model `Stat` with a jsonb field `data`. I have a large concurrency happening, with several asynchronous processes which will add their own line in the jsonb field `data`.

To test the concurrency resiliency, I created an Rspec test. It adds a key value pair `{"<index>" => "ok"}` to the `data` jsonb field 20 times. At the end, I get a random length for the data field. If it was resilient, the length should be always "20".

```
threads = 20.times.map.with_index do |_, index|
       Thread.new do
             stat = Stat.find(stat_id)
             stat.with_lock do
                   stat.update!(data: stat.data.merge({index => "ok"}))
             end
       end
end
      
threads.map &:join
stat = Stat.find(stat_id)
expect(stat.data.length).to eq(20)
```

Answer (score 1):

The default in Rails is for a test example to be run in a single transaction, which is then rolled back at the end of the test to restore the DB to its pristine state. This means that despite you creating all those threads, they're all being funneled into the same DB connection from the pool which means the lock in each thread is not isolated from the others.

If you switch off `use_transactional_fixtures` then you'll see the behavior you want (RSpec::Rails v6 has a neat helper for switching off transactional tests), although you'll also need to clean up the DB yourself. Throw this in your test:

```rb
include RSpec::Rails::FixtureSupport
uses_transaction "the name of your test"
after { Stat.delete_all }
```

You'll also probably need to up your connection pool size in your `database.yml` so you have at least 20 connections available.